# JSON SelectTokens expression

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON file (below). My goal is to, fill a dictionary with `unit_ids` (f.e. in this JSON `unit_ids` are: `153470`, `153471` and `178903`) and corresponding `classtype_id` (f.e. in this JSON corresponding `classtype_id` are: `CW`,`CW`, `null`). (`unit_ids` are uniqe)

So f.e. my dictionary might be: `{[153470, CW]`,`[153471, CW]`,`[178903, null]}`.

But there is a problem, in my current approach, because of the possibility of: `"unit_id":null` like f.e. in this file: `"178903": null`.

```
Dictionary<string, string> unit_id_translate = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var unitIdsTypes = JObject.Parse(unit_ids_json).SelectTokens("*.['classtype_id']");
var unitIdsNumbers = JObject.Parse(unit_ids_json);
List<String> tempForUID = new List<String>();
List<String> tempForVAL = new List<String>();

foreach (var unitIdType in unitIdsTypes)
{
    tempForVAL.Add(unitIdType.ToString());
}

foreach (var unitIdNumber in unitIdsNumbers)
{
    foreach (var tmp44 in unitIdNumber)
    {
        var trimmedNr = unitIdNumber.Cast<JProperty>().Select(o => o.Name);
        foreach (var unitIdNr in trimmedNr)
        {
                tempForUID.Add(unitIdNr);
        }
        break;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < tempForUID.Count(); i++)
{
    unit_id_translate.Add(tempForUID.ElementAt(i), tempForVAL.ElementAt(i));
}
```

I need help, because my solution crashes (out of range exception) - there is more `unit_ids` than `classtype_id` - because of the `null` value.

What I can do to fix this ?

```
{
  "153470": {
    "topics": {
      "en": ""
    },
    "classtype_id": "CW",
    "learning_outcomes": {
      "en": ""
    },
    "course_id": "06-DRSOLI0",
    "course_name": {
      "en": "Distributed operating systems"
    },
    "id": 153470,
    "teaching_methods": {
      "en": ""
    }
  },
    "153471": {
    "topics": {
      "en": ""
    },
    "classtype_id": "CW",
    "learning_outcomes": {
      "en": ""
    },
    "course_id": "06-DPROLI0",
    "course_name": {
      "en": "Team project"
    },
    "id": 153471,
    "teaching_methods": {
      "en": ""
    }
  },
    "178903": null,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with [`Enumerable.ToDictionary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548657%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
        var unit_id_translate = JObject.Parse(unit_ids_json)
            .Properties()
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => (string)p.Value.SelectToken("classtype_id"));
```

Then

```
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(unit_id_translate));
```

produces `{"153470":"CW","153471":"CW","178903":null}`.